# Stuggling to understand ideal powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In my current algebraic number theory course we have defined the multiplication of 2 ideals as the smallest ideal containing all products of elements of both,

[i.e: let I and J be ideals of a ring R, then
IJ:={$\sum_1^k a_ib_i : a_i\in I , b_i\in J$} where k depends on R ]

we haven't however, formally defined ideal powers, by which I mean ideals of the form $I^x$ where x is an integer.

However, using the first, informal definition, it seems to me that all products of elements from I will just again form I

i.e. using the formal definition, and taking x = 2 I find that

$I^2$ = II = {$\sum_i^k a_ib_i : a_i\in I , b_i\in I$} = {$\sum_1^k c_i : c_i\in I$} = {$d : d\in I$} = I

and clearly extending this definition to higher powers results in the same thing?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: The equality between the first and the second line is not true in general. Not every element in $I$ can be written as a product of two elements in $I$. For example, the element $2$ in the ideal $2\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z$ cannot be written as a product of two elements in $2\Bbb Z$. So the transition from the first to the second line is "is a subset of", which can be proper in some cases.

Comment: thank you! sorry I was still in the editing process before posting, but I assume you mean $I^2$ =/= $II$ ? and if so, do you know of a recognized definition of $I^2$ or is this something specific to my course? thanks again

Comment: $I^2$ is precisely $I\cdot I$. My point is that $I^2$ contains (sums of) products of elements of $I$, which may be a proper subset of $I$. Now that you have changed the formatting, the crucial point is the third equality sign. All the rest is fine.

Comment: got you, thanks so much, you are a star!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third equality sign in your chain of equalities is, in fact, only $\subseteq$.

There is no reason to expect that every sum of elements in $I$ can be expressed as a sum of products of two elements of $I$.

To pick an analogy from group theory and sidestep the added complexity of the sums needed for products of ideals: for an abelian group $G$ (say, for example, the multiplicative group of positive rationals) the subset $H=\{x^2\mid x\in G\}$ turns out to be a subgroup of $G$. But, of course, not every rational is the square of a rational, so $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

It's simple to give examples of ideals to convince you of the inequality too, and the one given by zarathustra in the comments is hard to improve upon:  $I=2\mathbb Z\lhd \mathbb Z$ is an ideal, and every product of two elements in $I$ is divisible by $4$, so $I^2\neq I$.